# When mathematicians say "true" do they mean "true in all models"?

Tags: logic, terminology, philosophy

According to the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4868582/1209102),

> Truth is ordinarily defined by reference to models.

If so, even axioms and theorems are not true without reference to a model.

However, when mathematicians say "this is true," they are usually not referring to a specific model. Is he saying "true in all models"?

Comment: There is a theorem of logic saying that given any statement, for that statement to be "true in all models" is equivalent to being provable from the axioms. I'll repeat my earlier recommendation: you might like a good book on model theory.

Comment: What do you see ‘all models’ being? Perhaps all models within a system of models?

Comment: @LeeMosher that only holds for logics and theories with sound and complete proof systems.

Comment: Not necessarily: mathematical axioms are not true in **all** models

Comment: @PW_246 Which logic applies to it and which does not? What about ZFC?

Comment: @MathMan First-Order Logic has a sound and complete proof system, but Second-Order Logic does not. ZFC is incomplete in the sense that you can’t prove or refute an arbitrary formula of ZFC.

Comment: The theorems of ZFC are true in every model of the axioms. But there are statements in the language of the theory that are independent wrt the axioms, like CH: they are true in some model and false in others.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your question but otherwise I think it seems fair to add that virtually no mathematician has any idea of models or even logic in any broader sense (not to mention philosophy). So most of the time the word 'true' isn't somehow defined or anything, it is just that word of natural language and may mean whatever anybody anywhere anytime means with it. Also, even if given a more formal definition, isn't it used on the meta-level in a primitive, intuitive way?

Comment: For otherwise you wouldn't have that something is true in some model, because then also $\textit{that}$ would be true only in some model, and also $\textit{that}$...and so on.. At least so it seems to me.